# OrientDB Linklist limit

Tags: types, computer-science, orientdb

The OrientDB List list is limited to 41,000,000 items:
[OrientDB Supported Types](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Types.html)

The other types have meaningful bounds, mostly around byte lengths, but 41,000,000 seems both specific and arbitrary. Why this limit?